# Union of data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 4 dataframes in a list L like below:

```
L[[1]]:

V1   V2
B    C
A    B
Z    B

L[[2]]:

V1   V2
B    D
A    B
Z    B

L[[3]]:

V1   V2
Z    Y
X    Z
N    Z

L[[4]]:

V1   V2
Z    J
X    Z
N    Z
```

This come from graph with the head C,D,Y, and J.
Obviously, C and D is from the same graph, so is Y and J.
How can I merge C with D and Y with J given these dataframes is in a list L?

What I'm thinking is, to iterate the list and pairwise comparison. If dfx intersect with dfy merge. Anyone can help with the R code?

Edit:
What I'm thinking is like this:
Get first element, compare to second, if okay, merged and save to the first element, remove the second element, move to next element until last. Repeat until remaining element not removed. With this, the list will consist of remaining element which has been merged  Anyone know how to implement this in the code?
Output expected :

```
L[[1]]:

V1   V2
B    C
B    D
A    B
Z    B

L[[2]]:

V1   V2
Z    Y
Z    J
X    Z
N    Z
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I expect list of the merged. With the example I gave, it will be list with 2 elemen, merged of C and D and the other is merged of D and Y.

Comment: Perhaps `Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = "V1"), list(mget(paste0("df", 1:4))))`

Comment: It is better to update your post with the expected output so that it becomes easier

Comment: What I meant by expected output is to show the output just like you showed the initial datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be an approach to a solution for you?

```
# create list of data.frames
ld <- list(
  data.frame(V1 = c("B","A","Z"), V2 = c("C","B","B")),
  data.frame(V1 = c("B","A","Z"), V2 = c("D","B","B")),
  data.frame(V1 = c("Z","X","N"), V2 = c("Y","Z","Z")),
  data.frame(V1 = c("Z","X","N"), V2 = c("J","Z","Z"))
  )
# suggested solution
union_ld <- data.table::rbindlist(ld)
unique(union_ld)
```

Results:

```
   V1 V2
1:  B  C
2:  A  B
3:  Z  B
4:  B  D
5:  Z  Y
6:  X  Z
7:  N  Z
8:  Z  J
```

## Update 1

Quick hack: two data frames in a list as requested by the OP. According to comment of OP, the order of the rows within each result data frame doesn't matter.

```
list(
  unique(data.table::rbindlist(ld[1:2])),
  unique(data.table::rbindlist(ld[3:4]))
)
```

results in:

```
[[1]]
   V1 V2
1:  B  C
2:  A  B
3:  Z  B
4:  B  D

[[2]]
   V1 V2
1:  Z  Y
2:  X  Z
3:  N  Z
4:  Z  J
```

The proposed solution combines the first two data frames in the list into one data frame, removes the duplicate rows. This is repeated for the last two data frames in the list. Then, the resulting data frames are combined to a list again.

## Update 2

This solution uses `rbindlist` from package `data.table`. If you don't like this, the result can be returned as "pure" data frames like this

```
library(data.table)
list(
  setDF(unique(rbindlist(ld[1:2]))),
  setDF(unique(rbindlist(ld[3:4])))
  )
```

## Update 3

According to OP's comment there are more data frames which need to be combined in several groups.

```
# set up a list of vectors of numbers of data.frames to combine
dfs_to_combine <- list(c(1:2), c(3:4))
dfs_to_combine

[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 3 4

# now, combine data.frames as specified
library(data.table)
lapply(dfs_to_combine, function(x) setDF(unique(rbindlist(ld[x]))))

[[1]]
  V1 V2
1  B  C
2  A  B
3  Z  B
4  B  D

[[2]]
  V1 V2
1  Z  Y
2  X  Z
3  N  Z
4  Z  J
```

This is just to reproduce your initial example. If you want to combine differently change the numbers, e.g.,

```
dfs_to_combine <- list(c(1), c(2, 4), c(3))
```

Comment: The result should have a list with 2 elements like I post above.

Comment: @Bharata Is the order of results relevant?

Comment: No, the order is no concern.

Comment: @Bharata If my solution is OK for you would you mind to accept it? Otherwise, please, let me know where your expectations aren't met, yet. Thank you.

Comment: I am still trying to do this because the actual dataframe in the list is more than 2, around 32 dataframes and can be merged into more than 2 groups.

Comment: @Bhrata Perhaps, you should have mentioned the complexity of the task in your question. However, I think this one should work for you, if you can specify `dfs_to_combine` manually or programmatically.

Comment: @Bharata Did you try my solution shown in Update 3?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.